# Tabla de multiplicar con Arrow Functions en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

hola estoy haciendo unos ejercicios en JS usando Arrow Functions, el ejercicio "Programa que muestre la tabla de multiplicar según un multiplicando, hasta un
multiplicador de 0 hasta un valor ingresado usando un Arrow Functions"

```js
let valor = "";
let multi = () =>{

    for (let i = 0; i < m2; i++) {
        let r = m1 *i;
        valor = valor + m1 + " x " + i + " = " + r + "<br>"; 
        
    }
    
}
const m1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicando"));
const m2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicador"));
alert(multi(`${m1,m2}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que te funcione tal cual como tienes tu código solo te falta un

> return

para que imprimas tu resultado

```js
let valor = "";
let multi = () =>{

    for (let i = 0; i < m2; i++) {
        let r = m1 *i;
        valor = valor + m1 + " x " + i + " = " + r + "\n"; 
        
    }
    return valor;
    
}
const m1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicando"));
const m2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicador"));
alert(multi(`${m1,m2}`));
```

y por ultimo cambiar los **br** por **\n**

Recuerda que los br son para html.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, anteriormente lo hice así pero parece que retorne los datos equivocados, me salvaste de una :D

Comment: Dale. para ayudarnos, espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que

1. Pasar los parametros a la funcion multi()
2. usar un console log dentro del for

Cambie tu codigo porque tiene varios errores como variables usadas pero sin declarar.

```js
let valor = "";
    let multi = (a, b) =>{
    
        for (let i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            let r = a *i;
            let valor =  a + " x " + i + " = " + r + "<br>"; 
            console.log(valor)
        }
        
    }
    const m1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicando"));
    const m2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar Multiplicador"));
    multi(m1, m2)
```

Comment: gracias me funciono correctamente

Answer (score 0):

> No había leído tu comentario posterior donde detallabas lo que te
> pedían
> para ver con alert()

```
let valor:string[] = [''];
    const multiOpe = (a: string | null, b: string | null) => {
      let op1 = parseInt(a!);
      let op2 = parseInt(b!);
      let resultados;
      for (let i = 0; i <= op2; i++) {
        let result = op1 * i;
     resultados = op1 + " x " + i + " = " + result+''+'';
         armarTabla(resultados);
        console.log(resultados);

      }
    }
    function armarTabla(param:string){
      valor.push(param)
}
const m1 = prompt("Ingresar Operando 1");
    const m2 = prompt("Ingresar Operando 2");

multiOpe(m1, m2);
 alert(valor.join('\n'))
```

> se mostraria asi
> [image: con alert()]
>
> ver tabla  solo en consola

let valor = "";

```
    const multiOpe = (a: string | null, b: string | null) => {
      let op1 = parseInt(a!);
      let op2 = parseInt(b!);
      for (let i = 0; i <= op2; i++) {
        let result = op1 * i;
         let valor = op1 + " x " + i + " = " + result;

        console.log(valor)

      }
    


    }
    const m1 = prompt("Ingresar Operando 1");
    const m2 = prompt("Ingresar Operando 2");

multiOpe(m1, m2);

/*
Por ejemplo ingresando 
operando 1=5
operando 2=7
5 x 0 = 0
5 x 1 = 5
... y asi hasta 
5 x 7 = 35


*/
```

Comment: pues segun el enunciado me pide que haga una tabla de multiplicar según un multiplicando, hasta un multiplicador de 0 hasta un valor ingresado, por ello uso el ciclo for para mostrar poder ejecutar el problema.

las respuestas anteriores muestran la respuesta correcta

Comment: La opción de Marcar como correcta es cuando estés seguro que esa es la respuesta que buscas para que un futuro si alguien va a buscarla encuentre la solución también

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Tranquilo, recuerda que siempre hay mas como tu que pueden necesitar ayuda con un problema parecido y la idea es que encuentren la respuesta que les ayude

Comment: DanGosw no había leído tu comentario edito mi solución para que sea tipo tabla -->operando 1 se multiplica hasta el operando 2

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio  esta nueva respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: estas haciendo un curso de javascript? donde? si te sirvió podes marcarla como útil saludos

Comment: De hecho son Ejercicios de mi carrera de computacion e informática, agradezco de antemano tu ayuda